# Cannot push value to second output field

Tags: javascript

I just finished the W3 Schools certification course on JavaScript.

Can somebody explain why the `returnValue()` function works for the `inField` element, but not for the `output` element.

I'm guessing I have to create a variable and then reference the variable with the `output` element. Even if that is the solution I'd like to understand the logic behind this necessity.

Any assistance is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='output'>Output: </div>     
        <div> Enter a value: <input type="text" id="inField"> </div>
        <button onclick="returnValue()" id="submit">Submit</button> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function returnValue() {
    document.getElementById("inField").value="Test";
    document.getElementById("output").value="Test";
}
```

Comment: inField is a form element with a `property` field. `output` is an html element and the property you want for that is `innerHTML` instead of value

Comment: `div` tags don't have a `value` attribute. [Here is a list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) of elements that do have the value attribute, but keep in mind the `input` tag is the only one where the `value` attribute is actually displayed on the page. For anything besides `input`, set the `innerText` attribute instead.

Comment: The code could be collapsed to `document.getElementById("inField").value = document.getElementById("output").textContent = "Test";` if you don't care about the existing "Output: " text remaining. However, I suggest you learn about `addEventListener` and move away from using HTML attributes for event handler attachment.